# Map function bot return markup in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React app I am working on and right now I am mapping over an object and trying to return a component for each iteration. Currently I can map over the object and console log the object of each iteration. However for some reason when I try to return my component(or even just simple mark up) nothing shows up in the browser.

Currently I am maping the object like this:

```
<ul>
     {Object.keys(weatherData).map(item => <ListItem item={weatherData[slug(item)]} key={slug(item)} clickAction={updateDisplay} />)}
</ul>
```

This also does not work, so I know its not my component:

```
<ul>
     {Object.keys(weatherData).map(item => <p>Hello</p>)}
</ul>
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening? It is only in this map where my mark up doesn't work!

**This is what the locations object looks like:**

```
{
     Managua: {country: "Nicaragua", capital: "Managua", type: "countryCapital", weatherData: Object},
     Wellington: {country: "New Zealand", capital: "Wellington", type: "countryCapital", weatherData: Object}
}
```

**So weatherData looks like this**

`{country: "New Zealand", capital: "Wellington", type: "countryCapital", weatherData: Object}`

Comment: What is `weatherData` -- could you give us a sample of the object?

Comment: @AndrewLi just added what WeatherData looks like

Comment: Is `weatherData` an array of objects like the example? Or is that the entire `weatherData` object?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody It is a json object, I just provided an example.

Comment: How are you getting `weatherData` from the JSON?

Comment: I suspect maybe the data isn't coming in right away?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Can you show the full component, because everything is here, and it should not show anything unless you get an empty "weatherData", but you said you can see the logs from the map, so... we need more information